# python lxml inkscape namespace tags

Tags: python, svg, lxml, inkscape

I am generating an SVG file that's intended to include Inkscape-specific tags. For example, `inkscape:label` and `inkscape:groupmode`. I am using lxml etree as my parser/generator. I'd like to add the `label` and `groupmode` tags to the following instance:

```
layer = etree.SubElement(svg_instance, 'g', id="layer-id")
```

My question is how do I achieve that in order to get the correct output form in the SVG, for example:

```
<g inkscape:groupmode="layer" id="layer-id" inkscape:label="layer-label">
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, remember that `inkscape:` isnt' a namespace, it's just a convenient way of referring to a namespace that is defined in your XML root element.  The namespace is `http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape`, and depending on your XML, `inkscape:groupmode` might be identical to `foo:groupmode`.  And of course, your `<g>` element is part of the SVG namespace, `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`.  To generate appropriate output with LXML, you would start with something like this:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.Element('{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}svg')
g = etree.SubElement(root, '{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}g', id='layer-id')
```

Which would get you:

```
<ns0:svg xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <ns0:g id="layer-id"/>
</ns0:svg>
```

To add in the inkscape-specific attributes, you would do this:

```
g.set('{http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape}groupmode', 'layer')
g.set('{http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape}label', 'layer-label')
```

Which would get you:

```
<ns0:svg xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <ns0:g xmlns:ns1="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" id="layer-id" ns1:groupmode="layer" ns1:label="layer-label"/>
</ns0:svg>
```

Which believe it or not is exactly what you want.  You can clean up the namespace labels a bit by passing an `nsmap=` parameter when creating your root element.  Like this:

```
NSMAP = {
  None: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
'inkscape': 'http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape',
}

root = etree.Element('{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}svg', nsmap=NSMAP)
```

With this in place, the final output would look like this:

```
<svg xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="layer-id" inkscape:label="layer-label" inkscape:groupmode="layer"/>
</svg>
```

More information in the [LXML documentation](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces).