# Getting inkscape attribute with d3

Tags: svg, d3.js, inkscape

I need to extract inkscape label attribute for a group node in a SVG file created with Inkscape:

SVG:

```
<g id="g123" inkscape:label="group 1">...</g>
```

Code:

```
d3.select("#g123").attr("inkscape:label"); // return null
```

Register inkscape namespace does not work either:

```
d3.ns.prefix.inkscape = "http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape";
d3.select("#g123").attr("inkscape:label"); // return null
```

Even though this works:

```
d3.select("#g123").node().getAttribute("inkscape:label")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
d3.select("#g123").node().getAttribute(":inkscape:label")
```

Read this posts to see why: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806088/python-lxml-inkscape-namespace-tags) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857781/d3-get-attribute-with-special-character).