# d3 get attribute with special character

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Lately I have been researching how to modify SVG files with d3.js.
Till thus far it has been a great tool to work with but now I ran in a little problem.
I create a SVG file with inkscape (a tool we have to use is build in it) and it will leave a extra attribute on the SVG file we have to read (inkscape:label) inside this extra attribute we find a Json string with some extra data on how to animate the object.

However I can't seem to read the special character because of the : in it.
If I remove it in the image it is fine. I also tried to escape the special character with `\u003A` (unicode for :) but nothing seems to help.

However if I use native javascript `getAttribute("inkscape:label")` it works perfectly. But sadly this isn't a solution because it will break some d3 stuff.

How can I do the same with d3.js?

SVG File (the attribute is at the bottom):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48+devel r12830"
   onload="var src; if (document.documentURI) src = document.documentURI; else if (this.getSrc) src = this.getSrc(); else src = document.location.href + ''; try {parent.preload.load(src);}catch(e) {}"
   viewBox="0 0 744.09447 1052.3622"
   sodipodi:docname="drawingSVG.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35"
     inkscape:cx="-823.57143"
     inkscape:cy="520"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1027"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="22"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Laag 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       sodipodi:type="star"
       style="fill:#ffff00;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="path3262"
       sodipodi:sides="5"
       sodipodi:cx="237.14284"
       sodipodi:cy="232.36218"
       sodipodi:r1="172.02278"
       sodipodi:r2="86.011391"
       sodipodi:arg1="2.1311562"
       sodipodi:arg2="2.7594747"
       inkscape:flatsided="false"
       inkscape:rounded="0"
       inkscape:randomized="0"
       d="M 145.71427,378.07647 157.33485,264.43467 70.307332,190.43663 181.97807,166.37122 225.4614,60.736482 l 57.39572,98.768558 113.9017,8.71217 -76.19823,85.10774 26.91179,111.01916 -104.48882,-46.16908 z"
       inkscape:transform-center-x="3.6097674"
       inkscape:transform-center-y="-12.95571"
       inkscape:label="{&quot;attr&quot;:&quot;color&quot;,&quot;list&quot;:[{&quot;data&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;param&quot;:&quot;#EF8C8C&quot;,&quot;tag&quot;:&quot;aTag&quot;}]},{&quot;attr&quot;:&quot;opac&quot;,&quot;max&quot;:20,&quot;min&quot;:0,&quot;tag&quot;:&quot;aTag2&quot;}" />llk
  </g>
</svg>
```

and I try to get the value of the inkscape:label attribute with:

```
console.log(d3.select("#path3262").attr("inkscape:label"));
```

sadly that didn't work neither does

```
console.log(document.getElementById("path3262").getAttribute("inkscape\u003Alabel"));
```

if I access it with

```
console.log(document.getElementById("path3262").getAttribute("inkscape:label"));
```

it works or if I change the inkscape:label inside the svg file and the d3 code it also works

Comment: Hmm, have you tried something like `.attr("svg:inkscape:label")`?

Comment: No I haven't tried that yet. However before it returned null now it just returns a empty string. does the svg you put before the attribute need to be changed to something else like a id or something?

Comment: No, that's the namespace, which I think your "inkscape:" is getting interpreted as. Could you provide a complete example please?

Comment: added the code samples in the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colon in a name usually defines the namespace for the name after the colon. D3 has code to deal with this, to avoid having to specify the namespace explicitly everywhere. Unfortunately, this breaks in your case as it tries to interpret the leading `inkscape` as a namespace.

The workaround is simple though -- simply add another colon as a prefix to your selector. D3 will extract this empty "namespace" and interpret the rest of the string as being in the default namespace.

```
console.log(d3.select("#path3262").attr(":inkscape:label"));
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DANx6/).