# Namespaced attributes in SVG (embedded in HTML document)

Tags: css, svg, d3.js

Using d3.js I want to insert attributes of a specific namespace into SVG elements (embedded in a HTML5 document), more precisely [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20265073/3874119).

So I have the following JavaScript:

```js
d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr({width: 100, height: 100})
    .append("rect")
        .attr({width: 100, height: 100})
        .attr("myns:foo", "bar");
```

CSS:

```css
rect[foo] {
    fill: red;
}

rect[myns\:foo] {
    fill: green;
}
```

Results in:

```html
<html>
  <head>…</head>
  <body>
    <svg width="100" height="100">
      <rect width="100" height="100" foo="bar"></rect>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

see **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6B4Pz/)**

I expected the generated rectangle to be green, but instead it is red. Also I wonder why the attribute is not `myns:foo`.

I also experimented with `d3.ns.prefix` (until I read [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24612294/3874119)) and the CSS3 `@namespace`, however without success.

So can you explain to me why the code above does not work as intended and could you provide an alternative?

Comment: Thanks to [that post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/4pOdrFpgjTo/24sTzQXJYAwJ) I was able to trick D3.js by writing `":myns:foo"`: http://jsfiddle.net/6B4Pz/1/ But I cannot believe that is the way to go…

Comment: I think that's the way to go, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857781/d3-get-attribute-with-special-character/23858218#23858218

Comment: Next problem: the result is invalid according to http://validator.w3.org/:
*Attribute myns:foo is not serializable as XML 1.0*,
*Attribute myns:foo not allowed on element rect at this point*. Adding `xmlns:myns="…"` to the SVG element produces even more errors.

Comment: It sounds like the answer is to not namespace your attribute names.

Comment: You might want to try using data attributes if you want to store arbitrary information on elements: `.attr('data-foo', 'bar')`

Comment: I use HTML5 data attributes right now and it works like a charm, but it seems like to be not supported officially (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15580322/3874119). But I want my application to satisfy the W3 validator. Maybe I will store the data in a HTML class which is actually suitable but leads to a small overhead on updating the data respective class (find old class; delete it; add new class). By the way, the guys at ArcGIS use data attributes (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/popup_relatedrecords.html). There's probably no way that fits all.

Comment: Can you explain why you need a custom attribute at all? The example looks like you can easily use a class name instead of `foo`. Then you would be in the clear!

Comment: The actual SVG contains multiple rectangles with properties like `color-1-of-5`, `color-2-of-5`,… and I want to update these properties (e. g. change the color of one rectangle from `color-3-of-5`to `color-4-of-5`). Using any kind of attribute I am able to just override the former property while the use of classes calls for deleting the former class first (which is not *that* easy if the rectangle has other classes I do not want to change). I am still torn between the different approaches.